# bootstrap button group size is different by text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my button group that using bootstrap template:

```
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        <label class="btn btn-default">%100</label>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>

   </div>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Button groups are not same alignment. I want fixed label size. This is an ugly appearence.

Comment: I don't get your question. What do you mean by fixed label size?

Comment: I updated posted image, the two buttons are not same alignment.

Comment: Ah you mean the width.. I just thought about font sizes, which didn't make sense. @Dhunt answered your question already then.

Comment: Yes I mean width,  thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try creating a css class to set the width of the text content:

```
.btn-group label{
    width: 100px;//or any other size
}
```